# Excel Workbook open macro reopens closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I do the following as a macro

1. Open a list of files
2. copy some values
3. Close them

After that when I exit and reopen the file that contains the macro, it also opens the files which I previously opened. even those I had used the app.workbook.close

I'm unable to find the problem out.

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: where is the macro located? in a normal module?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @whytheq I thought I figured it out ... but actually I didn't.. The error still occurs... Here's the code... I see that each time I use the code to open the file a new process is created. This doesn't shut down even if I close the files... but there isn't any error on my end. and I even checked whether the close command gets the proper Filename and it does..

Here's the code.

Set currentWB = app.Workbooks.Open(myFile.Path)
'lots of other commmands
app.Workbooks(myFile.Path).Close SaveChanges:=False

Comment: at the end you may aswell say `currentWB.close False` seeing as how you've already pointed the variable at it. Then to close `Set currentWB = Nothing`. Are there some links between the file that has the macro and the files it creates?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. but that Solves it ... Thanks :)

Comment: oh - let me copy the comments to an answer - maybe you can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the macro located? In a normal module?

At the end, seeing as how you've already pointed the variable at it, you may as well say

```
currentWB.close False
```

Then to close

```
Set currentWB = Nothing
```

Are there some links between the file that has the macro and the files it creates?